# What happens if you enter a Steam powered serial key by accident of a game you already owned?

Tags: steam

When you have a vast collection you might get confused. What happens if you try to activate a Steam powered game with a serial of a game you already owned? Does the key get lost? How can you tell if it was used?

Comment: This answer is not definitive, but I have entered a second key for a game which I already had in my library, and the second key counted as being used thereafter. It should be noted that this key was from a Humble Indie Bundle, and they *do* maintain the policy that only the purchaser is allowed to activate their own keys. That may have had some impact on the scenario.

Comment: Thank you @Lemmings19 That's the answer I was looking for. BTW, IMHO, the other question doesn't have a straight answer.

Comment: What I have noticed is the following: If you already have a game (steam id = 101) and you add the same game (id = 101), then Steam will notify that you already have the game in your library and the key will not be used. However, it gets a bit more complicated because of game bundles. Say you already have a game (id = 101) and you get a bundle (humble bundle for example) which includes id 101, 102 and 103, when you activate it, you will only get id's 102 and 103 and not another copy of 101. The key will be used and I am not sure if it will warn you that you already have 101.

Comment: If you have 101, 102 and 103 already and then you try activating a bundle with those three exact games (and only those). I am not sure if it will activate and you will get nothing or if it will inform you that you already have all 3 games and it won't use the key. Sorry about the use of id's, thought it was the easiest way of putting my point across.

Comment: @Lyrical how sure are you?

Comment: I'm fairly confident it works this way.